# Nokogiri XPath element with attribute

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have:

```
doc.xpath("//ns:table", 'ns' => NS).to_a
```

which gives me an array of three elements:

```
<ns:table id="***" code="MY_CODE" ...>
<ns:table id="***" ...>
<ns:table id="***" ...>
```

But searching for

```
doc.xpath("//ns:table[@code]", 'ns' => NS).to_a
```

or

```
doc.xpath("//ns:table[@code='MY_CODE']", 'ns' => NS).to_a
```

gives me an empty array. When I search by `@id`, it gives me just two tables without the one with code.

Does anyone have an idea why I can't get the one with code?

Comment: Can you give a full example showing the problem? There isn’t really enough to go on here – this works as expected for me.

Comment: It looks good to me too, we have similiar code (same xpath) in different project working with same xml strctures and it works as expected. I dont realy want to share the xml here though. I was just wondering if you happen to know what can cause such behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as it'll help you write a usable question. As is, you're missing a minimal example of your input XML and need a better example of your code.